# Postgresql: user role with "\" in name

Tags: postgresql, roles

I made a typo while creating a role. Now I'm stuck with "\ruser" and I have no clue how to properly drop that role. Escaping the backslash in any kind of way doesn't work, using unicode formating doesnt work (drop role U&'%0Dmyuser';) or any kind of string markings (",',`) won't work. Any ideas?

```
server=# \du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 \rmyuser  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB                          | {}
 myuser    | Superuser, Create role, Create DB                          | {}
```

Comment: Short answer: dont do that ever again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply escape the identifier with double quotes:

```
DROP ROLE "\rmyuser";
```

In the case that `\r` is not a backslash and an `r`, but an escaped version of "carriage return", the simplest way may be to use dynamic SQL, the extended string literal syntax and the `format` function:

```
DO $$BEGIN EXECUTE format('DROP ROLE %I', E'\rmyuser'); END;$$;
```

Comment: This was the first thing I tried but, as mentioned in the question, none of the string markings I could think of helped.
```ERROR:  role "\rmyuser" does not exist```

Comment: Are you using some weird client that has problems with quotes or backslashes? It should work.

Comment: I use "Visual Code", do you consider this a weird client?

Comment: Personally, yes, since i have never heard about it. But it occurs to me that your user name might contain an carriage return, so I have added a new option to the answer.